# App is throwing an exception "Not in the main thread" when it's trying to add a marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, exception

Firstly the MapFragment downloading clinic's data (name, description, coordinates on a map, etc.) then it's trying to add a marker of them. And when the fragment is trying it the app throwing an exception that this line is not in the main thread.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
Process: com.happs.medrate, PID: 4332
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.c: Not on the main thread
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.m.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831046@19.8.31 (040306-0):22)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.r.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831046@19.8.31 (040306-0):5)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bm.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831046@19.8.31 (040306-0):60)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831046@19.8.31 (040306-0):308)
    at ck.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831046@19.8.31 (040306-0):5)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.addMarker(Unknown Source:54)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source:48)
    at com.happs.medrate.view.main.MapFragment.onResult(MapFragment.java:87)
    at com.happs.medrate.view.main.MapFragment.lambda$zKz5SBiVflok9pIuOSBON5AS6Uk(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.happs.medrate.view.main.-$$Lambda$MapFragment$zKz5SBiVflok9pIuOSBON5AS6Uk.onResult(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.happs.medrate.model.clinicsdata.GetClinicsData$GetDataThread.run(GetClinicsData.java:61)
```

There is the code(only methods):

```
//onResult is for GetClinicsData class (it is a Thread class)
private void onResult(Clinic clinic, @Nullable Exception e){
    this.clinic = new Clinic(clinic.getName(), clinic.getAddress(), clinic.getDescription(), clinic.getGeoPoint());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(clinic.getGeoPoint().getLatitude(), clinic.getGeoPoint().getLongitude());
    markerOptions.position(coordinates);
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        } else {
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    } else {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        MyLocationListener.setUpLocationListener(getContext(), getActivity());
    }
}
```

I've already tried to make the "add marker" part in onMapReady but the fragment firstly preparing the map with onMapReady method and only then is downloading the clinic's data, so when it's trying to add marker it throws "NullPointerException" because it didn't get the clinic's data yet. I don't know what I should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `onResult()` is called after some asynchronous work is completed, and that this work is done on some thread other than the main/ui thread. Markers can only be added to a map on the main thread, so you need to find a way to execute your code on the appropriate thread.

If you have control over the caller of `onResult()`, that might be the best place to switch threads:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(this::onResult);
```

If you don't, you can do the thread switching inside of `onResult()`:

```
private void onResult(Clinic clinic, @Nullable Exception e){
    this.clinic = new Clinic(clinic.getName(), clinic.getAddress(), clinic.getDescription(), clinic.getGeoPoint());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(clinic.getGeoPoint().getLatitude(), clinic.getGeoPoint().getLongitude());
    markerOptions.position(coordinates);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    });
}
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use `runOnUiThread()`, then you can use a `Handler` to get the same results:

```
new Handler().post(() -> { /* your code here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      MapView mMapView = (MapView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
      mMapView.onCreate(dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
      mMapView.onResume();
      mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LatLng myLocation=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon));
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("My location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            float zoomLevel = (float) 16.0; //This goes up to 21
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, zoomLevel));  
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Please, add more explaination as to why your solution is working.